# Out Of Memory Errors with Sbt-Uglify (Play 2.3.7)

Tags: scala, requirejs, sbt, playframework-2.3, uglifyjs

I am having issues with the sbt-uglify plugin in my Play application. I have followed the documentation exactly from https://github.com/sbt/sbt-uglify.

In my `plugins.sbt` I add the plugin:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-uglify" % "1.0.3")
```

In my `build.sbt` I add uglify to the asset pipeline:

```
pipelineStages := Seq(uglify, digest, gzip)
```

I have at least 60 JavaScript files that are being optimized with uglify when I run: `sbt start` or `sbt dist`. I begin to see several warnings:

```
[error] WARN: Dropping unused function argument  
[error] WARN: Dropping unused function argument   
[error] WARN: Dropping unreachable code
```

I am used to seeing this when I run a similar project with fewer JS files. This continues until it gets to the point of no memory:

```
[error] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
```

I found a similar question being asked about this: [Play 2.3.6 Java - OutOfMemory errors w/ sbt-uglify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27162548/play-2-3-6-java-outofmemory-errors-w-sbt-uglify). This didn't seem to be answered and I had already tried increasing my memory limit.

The funny thing is that I can get it to work fine with RequireJS, which should be doing the exact same thing. I should be able to use either, correct?

Has anyone else encountered this problem or know a solution? I am not completely sure if this is an issue with Play, Uglify, or what.

I have added a test example that replicates this issue that you can clone and try for yourself: https://github.com/ascreamingweas/Sbt-Uglify-Test

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: I have come up with a test version that replicates this exact error when trying to optimize 60+ CoffeeScript files. You can view this here: https://github.com/ascreamingweas/Sbt-Uglify-Test. Thanks!

Comment: As a workaround you could try installing node JS and using the node SBT JS engine as instructed [here](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-js-engine). It's much faster and more efficient than the Java-based default (Trireme) in my experience, albeit less convenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same problem, the sbt-js-engine seems to have solved the issue :

Just make sure you add the plugin

`ddSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-js-engine" % "1.0.2")`

Also don't forget to install NodeJS either add

`JsEngineKeys.engineType := JsEngineKeys.EngineType.Node`

or

`export SBT_OPTS="$SBT_OPTS -Dsbt.jse.engineType=Node"`

Comment: Thank you for your response. We moved on to other options for now but I will certainly try this out.